# Does this program leak memory?

Tags: c++, windows

Due to the new usage for returning the process id? And how can i check when memory is begin leaked, throughtout debugging my application? (This length check on the explanation section really sucks =P)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Process.h"
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>



DWORD GetProcessId( const wchar_t* szProcess )
{
    if( szProcess )
    {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
        PROCESSENTRY32 *pe32 = new PROCESSENTRY32();
        memset( pe32, 0, sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 ) );
        pe32->dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
        //Process32First( hSnapshot, pe32 );
        while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, pe32 ) )
        {
            if( pe32->szExeFile && !wcscmp( szProcess, pe32->szExeFile ) )
            {
                CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
                return( pe32->th32ProcessID ); //   std::wcout << pe32->szExeFile << std::endl;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
    }
    return 0;
}

HANDLE GetProcessHandle( DWORD dwProcessId )
{
    if( dwProcessId )
        return( OpenProcess( PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, 0, dwProcessId ) );

    return 0;
}

bool WriteExternProcessMemory( HANDLE hProcess, void* pAddr, size_t uSize, const char* szWrite, LPCVOID outBuffer )
{
    if( pAddr && szWrite && hProcess )
    {
        DWORD dwOldProtect;
        if( !VirtualProtectEx( hProcess, pAddr, uSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect ) )
            return( !WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pAddr, outBuffer, uSize, NULL ) );
    }

    return false;
}
```

-Edit,
the usage is:

```
void *pRecv;
WriteExternProcessMemory( GetProcessHandle( GetProcessId( _T( "notepad.exe" ) ) ), (void*)0x401000, 2, "\x40\x40",  &pRecv );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is leaking:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 *pe32 = new PROCESSENTRY32();
```

Better use:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {0};
pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
//Process32First( hSnapshot, pe32 );
while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) )
...
```

Also, you're not closing the handle created at `GetProcessHandle`, which is also a leak.

Comment: There would be no problem returning pe32.th32ProcessID? I think i studied returning struct objects craeted on the stack causes undefined behavior.

Comment: `th32ProcessID` is a `DWORD`, namely an unsigned long. You return it by value, so there's absolutely no problem with that. You get the UD issue if you return _a reference_ to a variable that's on the stack and gets out of scope.

Comment: Oh yes true about CloseHandle( hProcess ), didnt notice it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Allocating memory without freeing it later, as your program does, constitutes a memory leak.

You can find leaks in your program by using a [memory leak detector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9815/Visual-Leak-Detector-Enhanced-Memory-Leak-Detectio).

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind is a wonderful tool to tell you about memory leaks. If you are compiling with debugging symbols (-g for GCC), it will even tell you what line the leak happened on!

http://valgrind.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows isn't a [supported platform](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html) for Valgrind.

Comment: It is, however, a supported platform for [Visual Leak Detector (VLD)](http://vld.codeplex.com/).